# Cannot get image to float right of text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the image to float next to the text and i cannot get it to work.  I want both the  text and picture to go below the navigation and logo.

here is html
    
    
    
        Jake Jones New Media Design

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="wrapper">

    <div id="logo"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="Art"></div>

 <ul id="Menu">

  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Web</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Campeign</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Print</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Motion</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>


    <div class="text">

            <p> The surfboard, one of the most fun toys around.  There is just one problem with it.  The majority of them are plain white.  There is no color and adding some stickers isn't a true way to express yourself!  With a little time and some common items from your garage or hardware, you can make it so much better.  You don't have to be a great artist or have lots of money to truly make that board your own.  This site is a simple guide with some tips and tricks for painting your surfboard.  When the waves aren't breaking and your looking at that board in the corner of your room, take some time and change it up!  Here are some art ideas. <a href="http://jsindustries.com/sprays" target="blank">Art Ideas</a> </p>



<div class="imgContainer">
        <img src="me.jpg" alt="Art" title="me">
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

here is css

```
.wrapper {
    margin:auto;
    width:1000px;       
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#Menu,
#Menu ul {
    list-style: none;
  }

#Menu {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
   margin-top: 85px;
  }

#Menu > li {
float: left;
}
#Menu li a {
display: block;
height: 2em;
line-height: 2em;
padding: 0 1.5em;
text-decoration: none;
 }

#Menu ul {
position: absolute;
display: none;
z-index: 999;
}

  #Menu ul li a {
   width: 50px;
 }

#Menu li:hover ul {
display: block;
  }

    /* Main menu
------------------------------------------*/
#Menu {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
background: #ffffff;
  }

   #Menu > li > a {
   color: #000000;
   font-weight: bold;
    }

 #Menu > li:hover > a {
background: #ffffff;
color: #7a0808;
 }

/* Submenu
 ------------------------------------------*/
   #Menu ul {
    background: #ffffff;
   padding: 0;
   list-style-type: none;
     }

   #Menu ul li a {
  color: #000000;
   }

  #Menu ul li:hover a {
   color: #7a0808;
  }

  /* Content
   ------------------------------------------*/
.text {
    clear: both;
}

p   {

    clear: both;
    width: 200px;
}


.imgContainer {
margin-top: 70px;
margin-right: 40px;
float:right;
clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the image *before* the paragraph.

```
<div class="text">

    <div class="imgContainer">
        <img src="me.jpg" alt="Art" title="me">
    </div>

    <p> The surfboard, one of the most fun toys around.  There is just one problem with it.  The majority of them are plain white.  There is no color and adding some stickers isn't a true way to express yourself!  With a little time and some common items from your garage or hardware, you can make it so much better.  You don't have to be a great artist or have lots of money to truly make that board your own.  This site is a simple guide with some tips and tricks for painting your surfboard.  When the waves aren't breaking and your looking at that board in the corner of your room, take some time and change it up!  Here are some art ideas. <a href="http://jsindustries.com/sprays" target="blank">Art Ideas</a> </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Building a portfolio side for school.  Still in the very rough beginning!

Comment: @JakeJones Welcome to stack overflow and web development :) Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it helped.